# Substring search to obtain approximate match from random binary sequence

Tags: python, algorithm, search, alignment, substring

I have a pseudo random binary{0,1} sequence(X) and a not-continuous sub-sequence(Y) of X. How can I match where the Y coincides with X with maximum matches or find out the alignment of Y w.r.t to X. 
Given:
1. Y is not continuous. 
2. Y is erroneous.

Given substring algorithms like the KMP, Rabin- Karp and Boyer Moore Horspool algorithm cannot be used as they are used to find the exact match.

I already implemented the above using autocorrelation but the time complexity of the algorithm is O(n*m) n- length of the sequence and m-length of the pattern.

pseudo code:(Auto-correlation):
Assuming I have the distance of each element of Y from the first element of Y.
    **d**=[list of distances of each element of Y from first element of y]

```
for index=0 to index=len(X)
  X1=extract list of d distance elements from X
  for index2=0 to index2=len(Y)
      if(Y[index2]^X1[index2])
          cost=cost+1
 find index with max cost
```

Is there any other string match algorithm that can be used for this ?

EDIT:

Adding an example of the problem.
PROBLEM STATEMENT:
    X-random sequence of {0,1} of length 1Million
    Y-subset of X (random, ordered 1000 elements of X selected).
**Y is erroneous.**
Relative indexes, with respect to the first element of Y, of each element, is known.
First element of Y is not necessarily the 0th element of X.
Find the At which index Y starts, i.e find position where Y aligns to X.

```
 Example:
 X=[0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0]
 y=[1,1,0,0]
 d=[0,3,4,8]

 alignment of Y w.r.t to X is 2nd index of X.
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem ?

Comment: thank you MBo. But my main aim is to align my sub string or sub sequence with respect to the primary sequence, which is random.

Comment: Perhaps an example would be useful for clarification.

Comment: Are the discontinueities of fixed length or are there variably many 0 and 1 in between the single runs? Your pseudo-code suggests no, but then the practical runtime would be more like O(c*n) with c maybe close to 2. (Hint: you should stay away from plucking out each and every X1-list)

Comment: The big-O is the limit an infinity, and we'll be long dead by then anyway. The question can be improved by stating approximate problem size, as the answer would depend on the length of the sequences (100s or 100s of millions?), and the tradeoffs you allow (is a "good enough" match OK, or are your searching for the provably best one?), but generally, this seems related to the genome alignment problem; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment may be a good starting point. $O(n m)$ seems reasonable for the shortest dist. match, but you can go lower with inexact matching (BLAST, FASTA...).

Comment: @kkm , true . The size of X is 1 to 2 million and the size of Y is 1000 to 2000.

Comment: @Vroomfondel the discontinuities are of different lengths, i.e. Y is a sub set of X but not a continuous sub-set , rather random  bit positions, if that is what you meant.

Comment: What I meant is whether the position of piece 2..n of Y are at a priori known positions relative to the 1st, or if there can be variably many bits in between.

Comment: yes, the position of piece 2 of Y are at a priori known positions relative to the 1st.